# Spivak contradiction proof for Spivak problem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, proof-verification

[image: Definition of bound]

[image: Proof of IVT]

Here is what I dont understand:

He says that $\alpha$ is **an** upperbound.  He says it is the least upperbound.

Then he finds that $x_1 \in A$

And that $x_1 > \alpha$

How does this contradict the fact that $\alpha$ is an upperbound? There can be infinitely many upperbounds as long as $x \le b$

$x +1$ is an upperbound,

$x+ \delta$ is an upperbound for any $\delta > 0$

Then how is this a contradiction that $\alpha$ is an upperbound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument can be thought as the following:

1. You assume the least upperbound $\alpha$ is such that $f(\alpha) < 0$.
2. You use continuity to find an interval centered at $\alpha$ where $f$ is negative within that interval.
3. You find a number $x_1$ that is greater than $\alpha$ and has the property that $f$ is negative.
4. This new number $x_1$ is a number in the set considered that is greater than $\alpha$.
5. If it is greater than $\alpha$ and is in the set, then $\alpha$ can't be an upper bound, can it? Remember that being an upper bound for $A$ means **all** $x$ in $A$ satisfy $x \leq \alpha$. You just found one $x_1$ in $A$ such that $x_1 > \alpha$.

Comment: But $b > \alpha$ so that automatically suggests $\alpha$ is **not** an upperbound.

Comment: Are they saying that $\alpha$ is not the **least** upperbound, or just not an upperbound? There is a major distinction.

Comment: @Amad27 He assumed $\alpha$ was the **least** upperbound, and showed that it can't even be **an** upperbound.

Comment: That just doesnt seem right. There are infinite upper bounds. If $B = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 /}$ then $2, 3, 4$ are all upperbounds, and $4 = \sup B$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144316/proof-of-bolzanos-theorem I think is a better proof involving $\sup$

Comment: @Amad27 For your set $B$ you are wrong. The elements $2,3$ aren't upper bounds. If you had said 10 or 20, then you'd be right. However this is a finite set, and in such cases the $\sup$ is always equal to the maximum element. Why doesn't it feel right? Sure, there are infinite upper bounds, and there exists a least upperbound. What the claim is discussing is that the least upperbound **cannot have the property that** $f(\alpha) < 0$.

Comment: Why arent $2,3$ upperbounds?

Comment: @Amad27 Is every element of $B$ less than or equal to $2$? Or $3$?

Comment: I see. Sorry. I understand now.

Comment: @Amad27 That's great! And what matters. :) Glad to help.